# Plot numpy.fft.fft2 output

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I'm trying to get a sense of the spatial frequencies present in a series of images I want to analyze. I decided to do this with the [`numpy.fft.fft2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html) function, but apparetly the output can't be plotted - can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Apparently this is happening because the output contains values like `0.+0.j` which` matplotlib can't deal with. But I don't know how to change them to something it *can* deal with either.

Here's a [minimal example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/8606917/raw/cb136b93b9f937a4e70e7b7254c805382add3148/imFreq?create=1) with my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib can only handle real values.  Your options are to take the real or imaginary parts of the results, or magnitude and maybe even phase.  These can be done with `numpy.real` or `numpy.imag`, or `numpy.abs` and `numpy.angle`.

Ultimately, I guess it just depends on what you want to know about your FFT.  People are usually most interested in the magnitude of FFT data, which suggests `abs`.  This gives you an idea of the "power" in the various frequencies.